# Spring 3.1 ehCache in jar and war where jar will be used within war: XML configuration

Tags: java, jar, war, ehcache, spring-3

In my Project I have been using **ABC jar** within **XYZ war**, both implementing **ehCache with Spring 3.1,xml-driven configuration**(we have ehCache.xml and then spring-context.xml where we are intercepting cache through Spring AOP in both the projects). And we are getting following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named [xxxxxx] for CacheableOperation[] caches=[Cxxxxxxxx] | condition='' | key='#xxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:163) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:443) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:173) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.createOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:404) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:192) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.infy.flypp.dao.ContentDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9443481.getContentById(<generated>) [cglib-2.2.2.jar:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

This is how we solved this issue:

1. We copied all the cache configuration from `ABCehCache.xml`(from ABC jar) to `XYZehCache.xml`(from XYZ war).
2. We deleted the `ABCehCache.xml`(from ABC jar) but all the configuration(like bean instantiation for `ehCache.xml` and Spring AOP) inside `ABC-spring.xml` will remain same.
3. In `XYZ-spring.xml`, We imported `ABC-spring.xml` and defined composite cache manager.

**Supported Configuration files:**

**ABC-spring.xml:**

```
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="CacheManager1" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:config-location="classpath:ABCEhcache.xml" />
```

**XYZ-spring.xml:**

```
<import resource="classpath*:ABC-spring.xml" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.CompositeCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManagers">
        <array>
            <ref bean="CacheManager1" />
            <ref bean="CacheManager2" />
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToNoOpCache" value="true" />
</bean>

    <bean id="CacheManager2" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
        p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:config-location="classpath:XYZEhcache.xml" />
```

Hope this will help!!